# Detect special keys from physical keyboard on iOS

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, keyboard-events

I'm trying to detect special keys in my Delphi iOS app using an external keyboard, a [Smart Keyboard for iPad](https://www.apple.com/it/shop/product/MJYR2ZM/A/smart-keyboard-per-ipad-pro-129-inglese-usa) in my case. Every key that is also present in the OS virtual keyboard works perfectly.. but everything else doesn't.

My goal is to detect when the user press "special" keys, like:

- Shift
- Control
- Option (alt)
- Command
- Arrow keys
- Tab

I made a simple test app using this method for open the keyboard on a generic `TFMXObject`

```
uses
  FMX.VirtualKeyboard,
  FMX.Platform;

procedure ShowKey(AControl: TFMXObject);
var
  LKeyboardService: IFMXVirtualKeyboardService;
begin
  LKeyboardService := nil;
  if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXVirtualKeyboardService, LKeyboardService) then
  begin
    LKeyboardService.ShowVirtualKeyboard(AControl);
  end;
end;
```

I tried to catch the KeyDown and KeyUp event on the form, on the TFMXObject called by that function, on a generic TEdit, but the event is never called for those special keys (except for arrow up and arrow down when a TEdit is selected)

I already read the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FMX.Controls.TControl.KeyDown) about the KeyDown event, but the event is not called at all for those keys

What can i do to detect KeyDown and KeyUp event for every possible key? Thank you!